# Python script input text not displaying entirely

Tags: python-3.x

I wanted to make a "mental calculation generator". I tried a lot of syntaxes, and I came up with this one:

```
import random
randomnum1=random.randint(0,10000)
randomnum2=random.randint(0,10000)
final=int(randomnum1+randomnum2)
userinput=(input(str(randomnum1)) + "+" +(str(randomnum2)) + "= ")
```

I haven't finished it and I wanted to test, but it only printed an input with the value of the variable randomnum1, for example, if randomnum1 was equal to 300, it would display an input with 300. I cannot understand the source of the problem. How do I do to make the input show num1 + num2 = [And there the user can input a number]

Comment: what do you mean by the user input? please state your question clearly

Comment: @yklsga Sorry, I edited my post

Comment: Unbalanced parens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You brackets are off, use this:

```
input(str(randomnum1) + "+" + str(randomnum2) + "= ")
```

or:

```
input("{} + {} =".format(randomnum1, randomnum2))
```

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe all this was just because of a misplaced bracket!